# how to connect panel with link label in C# windows forms

Tags: c#

I am trying to open a panel using link label in C# windows form
application.

```
private void linkLabel3_LinkClicked(object sender, LinkLabelLinkClickedEventArgs e)
{
    System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("panel2");           
}
```

Comment: What is the meaning of connecting to a panel?

Comment: `panel2.Show`, perhaps?

Comment: What panel are u talking about?

Comment: Do you mean a Windows form panel? if yes then understand that Process.Start() is used to start programs, not to show form controls.

Answer (score 0):

```
private void linkLabel3_LinkClicked(object sender, LinkLabelLinkClickedEventArgs e)
{
     panel2.Show(); // Show the panel if exist
}
```

OR

```
private void linkLabel3_LinkClicked(object sender, LinkLabelLinkClickedEventArgs e)
{
     Panel panel2 = new Panel(); // Create the panel
     this.Controls.Add(panel2);  // Add to form
     panel2.Show();              // Show the panel
}
```